# How to authenticate on Dockerhub before pulling docker:dind with Gitlab CI runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, dockerhub

When I run this Gitlab CI job on my own runner “myrunner”

```
test:
  tags: 
    - myrunner
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - echo "It works!"
  rules:
    - when: always
```

I get this error message:

```
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit (docker.go:142:1s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
```

How can I authenticate before pulling the image **docker:dind** to avoid the pull rate limit on **Dockerhub**?

**Steps to create own Gitlab runner:**

Start runner:

```
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
     -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
     -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
     gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

Register:

```
docker run --rm -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --executor "docker" \
  --docker-image docker:stable \
  --url "DOMAIN" \
  --registration-token "REGISTRATION_TOKEN" \
  --description "docker-runner" \
  --tag-list "myrunner" \
  --run-untagged="true" \
  --locked="false" \
  --access-level="not_protected" \
  --docker-volumes "/certs/client" \
  --docker-volumes /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --docker-privileged
```

Comment: I think docker hub should be seen like a private registry requiring authentication. There is several [ways](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-an-image-from-a-private-container-registry) to do this but in your case, I think you can [pass](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#configuring-a-runner) `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` as environment variable in your `config.toml`. Sorry, I did not test on my side.

Comment: @NicolasPepinster that's it!

Comment: Ah perfect, that's good :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I added this to my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variables:
    DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG: '{ "auths": { "https://index.docker.io/v1/": { "auth": "$DOCKER_AUTH" } }}'
```

The value of `$DOCKER_AUTH` can be generated with

```
echo -n "my_username:my_password" | base64
```

with the username/password for Dockerhub.

Comment: In addition, add the `DOCKER_AUTH` variable before the `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` on the ci file or on the repo variables.

Comment: how about if I enabled the 2fa, and I use the token instead??
`my_password` can replace with `user_token` ?